# Recursive Query for only the parent categories - By period

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL below , I need to display only the records of the current month and year.

```
SELECT y.desc_category as segment, sum( x.value) as total FROM (
SELECT category.id_category, category.desc_category, category.parent_id , c.value AS value
FROM category
INNER JOIN cashbook AS c ON category.id_category = c.category_id )AS x 
INNER JOIN category AS y ON x.parent_id = y.id_category
INNER JOIN user AS u ON y.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 3
GROUP BY y.desc_category
```

I asked this post [Mysql - Recursive Query for only the parent categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972638/mysql-recursive-query-for-only-the-parent-categories/37000447?noredirect=1#comment61938182_37000447) but there was no response and the question was another. Can anybody help me

**My schema:**

I have the following table `category`:

```
id | desc_cat       | parent_id
19 | Personal       | (null)
20 | Credit Card    | 19
21 | Academy        | 19
22 | Home           | (null)
23 | Water          | 22
24 | Energy         | 22
25 | Rent           | 22
```

And I have a table containing entries with name `cashbook`:

```
id  | value    | category_id | date
177 | 480.55   | 20          | 2016-05-01
178 | 100.00   | 24          | 2016-05-04
179 | 580.00   | 25          | 2016-05-05
180 | 80.00    | 21          | 2016-05-09
181 | 28.00    | 23          | 2016-05-11
```

Comment: Show your schema and the date related column  .. if you want a period of time you should have a date somewhere ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select year and month for date .. and group by

```
SELECT x.`year`, x.`month`, y.desc_category as segment, sum( x.value) as total FROM (
SELECT category.id_category, category.desc_category, category.parent_id , c.value AS value, 
       year(c.`date`) as `year` , month(c.`date`) AS `month`
FROM category
INNER JOIN cashbook AS c ON category.id_category = c.category_id ) AS x 
INNER JOIN category AS y ON x.parent_id = y.id_category
INNER JOIN user AS u ON y.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 3
GROUP BY y.desc_category, x.`year`, x.`month`
```

and a easy way for filtering by actual year and month is use having and now

```
SELECT x.`year`, x.`month`, y.desc_category as segment, sum( x.value) as total FROM (
SELECT category.id_category, category.desc_category, category.parent_id , c.value AS value, 
       year(c.`date`) as `year` , month(c.`date`) AS `month`
FROM category
INNER JOIN cashbook AS c ON category.id_category = c.category_id ) AS x 
INNER JOIN category AS y ON x.parent_id = y.id_category
INNER JOIN user AS u ON y.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 3
GROUP BY y.desc_category, x.`year`, x.`month`
having x.`year` = year(now())  and x.`month` = month(now())
```

Comment: By doing so, lose the grouping

Comment: Right. But which part (in the code) I am specifying the month 08 and 2016

Comment: you want only the period  08 - 2016?

Comment: Initially only current month andyear (but will eventually implement a dropdown to select the month)

Comment: I have update the answer with a having filter on current  date ..   hope this is what you are looking for  ..